# How to give an indiviual uitableview cell rounded borders

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a UIviewController, in the xib file I added 3 uitableview cells, but I want to give the top and bottom cells rounded corners similar to a grouped table look. How can I do this, also how can I add table cells to a uiviewcontroller progammatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach, but for this to work you'll need to have an image for top cell, bottom cell, and middle cell. This will help distinguish between the first row, middle rows and the bottom one.

```
    UIImage *rowBackground;
    UIImage *selectionBackground;
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"]; //Top Rounded
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected.png"]; //Top Rounded Selected
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];// Bottom Rounded
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"]; //Bottom Rounded Selected
        } else {
            rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"];
            selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"]; // Anything in the middle
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"];
    }

    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
    ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
```